# How to select unique entries from List<Operations> where, Operation.RRN is operation number,

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

The program has an Operation class that contains the RRN field. In the List, all operations are selected from the database (purchase, cancellation, return). How to select from this List entries that have not been canceled or redone by RRN. For example, there is a  operations

[image]

The code should only return the entry RRN = 000501327300, because for other operations have already been cancelled.

```
List<Operation> operations = opers.SelectMany(oper => opers.Where(u => u.RRN == oper.RRN && u.IsReturn == "Purchase"))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.RRN)
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .ToList();
```

This code returns all records where IsReturn = "Purchase", which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
list.GroupBy(x => x.RRN) //Group by this since there are many of the same in your data set
    .Where(grp => grp.All(itm => itm.Operation != "Cancelled" && itm.Operation != "Redone")) //Eliminate all groups that contain a cancelled or redone operation
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.ToList()) //Convert the grouping back to individual records
```

Comment: Returns all records